# Can we pass a timeout to selenium RemoteWebDriver constructor so that the session creation will throw a timeout exception?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar on a remote machine.

I run `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -timeout 7200 - maxSessions 5000` on the remote machine.

I use

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteURL), capabilities);
```

to get a remote web-driver object but in some cases (1/300), the above constructor blocks the thread and doesn't return for a long time(I had to reload the process after waiting for 2 hours).

I was wondering if i could somehow pass a timeout value in the constructor itself, so that it will throw a timeout exception or something.

Comment: Why don't you update selenium to latest 2.53.

Comment: does the newer version support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Java property flags must be specified before the "-jar" command line option...

```
java -Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout=7200 -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
```

Be aware that the timeout is in seconds.

Comment: this timeout specifies the time a session is allowed to live for. I am getting blocked during the session creation itself. 
I want to pass a timeout parameter for the session creation routine itself.